# Script returned '/usr/bin/awk: Argument list too long' in using -v in awk command

Tags: bash, csv, awk

Here is the part of my script that uses *awk*.

```
ids=`cut -d ',' -f1 $file | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g'`
awk -vdata="$ids" -F',' 'NR > 1 {if(index(data,$2)>0){print $0",true"}else{print $0",false"}}' $input_file >> $output_file
```

This works perfectly, but when I tried to get data to two or more files like this.

```
ids=`cut -d ',' -f1 $file1 $file2 $file3 | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g'`
```

It returned this error.

```
/usr/bin/awk: Argument list too long
```

As I researched, it was not caused by the number of files, but the number of *ids* fetched.

Does anybody have an idea on how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: You could always do the `cut` and `sed` in `awk` as well, jut write a `#!/bin/awk` script.

Comment: Can you show an example of your input data and your expected output? I doubt that `cut` and `sed` are needed at all. Just a single `awk`  program should be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the way you generate your `ids` so they come out one per line, like this, which I use as a very simple way to generate `ids` 2,3 and 9:

```
echo 2; echo 3; echo 9
2
3
9
```

Now pass that as the first file to `awk` and your `$input_file` as the second file to `awk`:

```
awk '...' <(echo 2; echo 3; echo 9) "$input_file"
```

In `bash` you can generate a pseudo-file with the output of a process using `<(some commands)`, and that is what I am using.

Now, in your `awk`, pick up the `ids` from the first file like this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ids[$1]++;next}'  <(echo 2; echo 3; echo 9)
```

which will set `ids[2]=1`, `ids[3]=1` and `ids[9]=1`.

Then pass both your files and add in your original processing:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ids[$1]++;next} {if($2 in ids) print $0",true"; else print $0",false"}'  <(echo 2; echo 3; echo 9) "$input_file"
```

So, for my final answer, your entire code will look like:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ids[$1]++;next} {if($2 in ids) print $0",true"; else print $0",false"}'  <(cut ... file1 file2 file3 | sed ...) "$input_file"
```

---

As @hek2mgl alludes in the comments, you can likely just pass the files which include the `ids` to `awk` *"as is"* and let `awk` find the `ids` itself rather than using `cut` and `sed`. If there are many, you can make them all come to `awk` as the first file with:

```
awk '...' <(cat file1 file2 file3) "$input_file"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an environment variable to pass the data to awk. In awk the environment variables are accessible via an array `ENVIRON`.

So try something like this:

```
export ids=`cut -d ',' -f1 $file | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g'`
awk -F',' 'NR > 1 {if(index(ENVIRON["ids"],$2)>0){print $0",true"}else{print $0",false"}}' $input_file >> $output_file
```

Comment: I tried this but,it  still returned the same error.

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 problems in your script:

```
awk -vdata="$ids" -F',' 'NR > 1 {if(index(data,$2)>0){print $0",true"}else{print $0",false"}}' $input_file >> $output_file
```

that could be causing that error:

1. `-vdata=..` - that is gawk-specific, in other awks you need to leave a space between `-v` and `data=`. So if you aren't running gawk then idk what your awk will make of that statement but it might treat it as multiple args.
2. `$input_file` - you MUST quote shell variables unless you have a specific purpose in mind by leaving them unquoted. If `$input_file` contains globbing chars or spaces then you leaving it unquoted will cause them to be expanded into potentially multiple files/args.

So try this:

```
awk -v data="$ids" -F',' 'NR > 1 {if(index(data,$2)>0){print $0",true"}else{print $0",false"}}' "$input_file" >> "$output_file"
```

and see if you still have the problem. Your script does have other unrelated issues of course, some of which have already been pointed out, and you can post a followup question if you want help with those, but just FYI that awk script could be written more concisely as:

```
awk -v data="$ids" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR > 1{print $0, (index(data,$2) ? "true" : "false")}'
```

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions, but they didn't work. It still returned "/usr/bin/awk: Argument list too long" error.

Comment: Then you have a bug somewhere else in the shell script that calls awk. You're passing **1** string as `data` and **1** file name - there's no way awk thinks there's too many arguments given that. Run `shellcheck` on your shell script and in particular look for mismatched quotes.